# My dll won't unload even when i unload appdomain

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain, domainunload

I can not understand why my DLL is still in the memory of the program after I did AppDomain.Unload. Can I do something wrong?

```
AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyAuthDomain");
appDomain.DoCallBack(load_Auth);

var isLogin = (bool)appDomain.GetData("IsLogin");

AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);

private static void load_Auth()
{
    var form = new Compiler(File.ReadAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\form.dll"), "form");
    form.InvokeMember("ShowDialog");

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("IsLogin", (bool)form.GetField("IsLogin")); 
    form.Unload();
}
```

**P.S.**
How i understand that the DLL remains in memory? NETUnpack tells me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps me

```
AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);

//GC
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```